# nodejs nginx 502 gateway error

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to use a nodejs app behind an nginx reverse proxy to handle the ssl

I have my app running on localhost:2000. I can confirm this as working with a curl command.

This is my nginx setup:

```
  # the IP(s) on which your node server is running. I chose port 3000.
upstream dreamingoftech.uk {
server 127.0.0.1:2000;
keepalive 16;
}
# the nginx server instance
server {
listen 0.0.0.0:80;
server_name dreamingoftech.uk;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
#HTTPS
server {
listen 443 ssl http2;

server_name dreamingoftech.uk;
access_log /var/log/nginx/dreamingoftech.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/dreamingoftech.error.log debug;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dreamingoftech.uk/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dreamingoftech.uk/privkey.pem;

include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

# pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers and much more can be added, see nginx config options
location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
  proxy_pass http://dreamingoftech.uk/;
  proxy_redirect off;
  #proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "";
  proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```

if I now curl https://dreamingoftech.uk, it takes a while but I do get the webpage delivered. albeit with the message:

> curl: (18) transfer closed with 1 bytes remaining to read

However when viewed from a browser I get a 502 gateway error.

I have checked the error log and this is the result: [ERROR LOG](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x2sqh7u3ts5x841/errorlog.txt?dl=0)

I can't understand why the reverse proxy is adding such a time delay into the process. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

PS: in the upstream config I have tried localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 to no avail

Comment: Are you sure your application does not act differently when behind the proxy, like acting different based on remote IP or such ?

Comment: @BrahmaDev If i'm being honest, I have no idea.... Im trying to learn all of this at the moment so I don't know how to test?

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the same configuration. Can you try the following

You can redirect all http to https

```
server {
    listen  80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

or for a specific site like this

```
server {
    server_name dreamingoftech.uk;
    return 301 https://dreamingoftech.uk$request_uri;
}
```

but choose only one for your case

and then you make sure you node server is running on http mode and **not** https.

Also you mentioned that you run node on port 3000, then use port 3000 and not 2000 as I can see in your config.

After you confirm the above redirect all packets into localhost like this

```
server {

    listen 443;
    server_name dreamingoftech.uk;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/dreamingoftech.uk/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/dreamingoftech.uk/privkey.pem;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://localhost:3000;
      proxy_read_timeout  90s;

      proxy_redirect      http://localhost:3000 https://dreamingoftech.uk;
    }
 }
```

Create a file and sum the above code put it in `sites-available` with a name like `dreamingoftech.uk` and the use `ln -s` to create a softlink into `sites-enabled`. go to your `nginx.conf` and make sure you include folder `sites-enabled`

Then **must restart** nginx to check if it works

Answer (score 0):

@Stamos Thanks for your reply. I tried that but unfortunately it didn't work. I decided to try the most basic node app I could still using the basic modules I am using.

I tried this and it worked straight away.

The problem is with my app therefore. I will spend time rebuilding and testing step by step until I find the issue,

Thanks for your time!